# HBase Master won't start

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh

I have HBase running in a CDH cluster 5.7.0. After several months running without any problems, hbase service stopped and now it's impossible to start the HBase master (1 master and 4 region servers).

When I try to start it at some point the machine hangs and the last thing I can see in the master log is:

```
2016-10-24 12:17:15,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recover lease on dfs file hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005528.log
2016-10-24 12:17:15,152 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recovered lease, attempt=0 on file=hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005528.log after 2ms
2016-10-24 12:17:15,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recover lease on dfs file hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005529.log
2016-10-24 12:17:15,179 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recovered lease, attempt=0 on file=hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005529.log after 2ms
2016-10-24 12:17:15,394 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recover lease on dfs file hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005530.log
2016-10-24 12:17:15,397 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recovered lease, attempt=0 on file=hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005530.log after 3ms
2016-10-24 12:17:15,405 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recover lease on dfs file hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005531.log
2016-10-24 12:17:15,409 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recovered lease, attempt=0 on file=hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005531.log after 3ms
2016-10-24 12:17:15,414 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:742)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:232)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ProcedureProtos$ProcedureWALHeader.parseDelimitedFrom(ProcedureProtos.java:3870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.ProcedureWALFormat.readHeader(ProcedureWALFormat.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.ProcedureWALFile.open(ProcedureWALFile.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.WALProcedureStore.initOldLog(WALProcedureStore.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.WALProcedureStore.initOldLogs(WALProcedureStore.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.WALProcedureStore.recoverLease(WALProcedureStore.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.start(ProcedureExecutor.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startProcedureExecutor(HMaster.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startServiceThreads(HMaster.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1756)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-24 12:17:15,427 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available
java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:742)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:232)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ProcedureProtos$ProcedureWALHeader.parseDelimitedFrom(ProcedureProtos.java:3870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.ProcedureWALFormat.readHeader(ProcedureWALFormat.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.ProcedureWALFile.open(ProcedureWALFile.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.WALProcedureStore.initOldLog(WALProcedureStore.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.WALProcedureStore.initOldLogs(WALProcedureStore.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.store.wal.WALProcedureStore.recoverLease(WALProcedureStore.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.start(ProcedureExecutor.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startProcedureExecutor(HMaster.java:1175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startServiceThreads(HMaster.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1756)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-10-24 12:17:15,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Successfully connected to /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50010 for BP-813663273-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-1460963038761:blk_1079056868_5316127
2016-10-24 12:17:15,442 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recover lease on dfs file hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005532.log
2016-10-24 12:17:15,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recovered lease, attempt=0 on file=hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005532.log after 2ms
2016-10-24 12:17:15,669 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recover lease on dfs file hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005533.log
2016-10-24 12:17:15,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSHDFSUtils: Recovered lease, attempt=0 on file=hdfs://namenode:8020/hbase/MasterProcWALs/state-00000000000000005533.log after 2ms
```

I'm afraid there's something corrupted in WALProcedureStore but I don't know how to keep digging to find the problem. Any clues? Can I start the Master freshly without trying to load a previous corrupted state?

**EDIT**:

I just saw [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14712) that I think is the same issue that is happening to me. Can I safely remove everything in `/hbase/MasterProcWALs` without deleting old data stored in hbase?

without

Thanks

Comment: You can try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068423/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAL or Write-Ahead-Log is an HBase mechanism to be able to recover modifications of data when everything crashes. Basically, every write operation to HBase will be logged in WAL before hand and if the system crashes and the data are still not persisted, then HBase would be able to recreate those writes from WAL.

This [article](http://www.larsgeorge.com/2010/01/hbase-architecture-101-write-ahead-log.html) helped me to understand better the whole process:

[image]

> The WAL is the lifeline that is needed when disaster strikes. Similar to a BIN log in MySQL it records all changes to the data. This is important in case something happens to the primary storage. So if the server crashes it can effectively replay that log to get everything up to where the server should have been just before the crash. It also means that if writing the record to the WAL fails the whole operation must be considered a failure.
>
> Let"s look at the high level view of how this is done in HBase. First the client initiates an action that modifies data. This is currently a call to put(Put), delete(Delete) and incrementColumnValue() (abbreviated as "incr" here at times). Each of these modifications is wrapped into a KeyValue object instance and sent over the wire using RPC calls. The calls are (ideally batched) to the HRegionServer that serves the affected regions. Once it arrives the payload, the said KeyValue, is routed to the HRegion that is responsible for the affected row. The data is written to the WAL and then put into the MemStore of the actual Store that holds the record. And that also pretty much describes the write-path of HBase.
>
> Eventually when the MemStore gets to a certain size or after a specific time the data is asynchronously persisted to the file system. In between that timeframe data is stored volatile in memory. And if the HRegionServer  hosting that memory crashes the data is lost... but for the existence of what is the topic of this post, the WAL!

The problem here was that because of [this bug (HBASE-14712)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14712) the WAL ended up having thousands of logs. Each time the master tried to become active it had that many different logs to recover, lease on, and read... that ended up ddosing the namenode. It ran out of tcp buffer space and everything crashed.

To be able to start the master I had to remove manually the logs under `/hbase/MasterProcWALs` and `/hbase/WALs`. After doing this the master was able to become active and HBase cluster went back online.

**EDIT:**

As Ankit Singhai pointed out, removing the logs in `/hbase/WALs` will result in data loss. Removing just the logs in `/hbase/MasterProcWALs` should be fine.

Comment: Removing /hbase/WALs will result in data loss, which is also unnecessary for above error. Removing /hbase/MasterProcWALs should fix the master startup issue.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer, however agree with @AnkitSinghal you should distinguish `/hbase/MasterProcWALs` that are used by HBase master to store DDLs from `/hbase/WALs` used by Region Servers to store data.