# "SocketException: No buffer space available" on Jersey Client

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I am using jersey-client (1.9) for calling api and everytime when i need to call a webservice i create a new client instance :

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
ClientResponse response = webResource
                .queryParam(PARAM1, param1)
                .queryParam(PARAM2, param2)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

the problem is after a period of time i get this exception :

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

If anyone could help me figure it out I would be very grateful .

Answer (score 1):

You have a resource leak. (Connections and InputStreams backing ClientResponses aren't being closed.) You can read a ClientResponse entity so that its associated resources are automatically closed by calling `ClientResponse.readEntity()`, or you can manually close them via `ClientResponse.close()`.

The following documentation may not exactly apply to the version of Jersey that you're using, but it's insightful:

[Jersey Client API, Closing connections](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/client.html#d0e5019)

Comment: but i always read the entity in my code like this :   final String responseFromWs = response.getEntity(String.class); so i dont need to close the response manually

Answer (score 1):

If you will provide additional details about the OS (windows/linux), more of the code or the type  load your service is experiencing - all would help to provide a better answer.

A good guess though is that your OS is running out of sockets ports.  Different OS's have different defaults and different ways of configuring how many sockets are available to establish TCP sockets.

though not exactly the same question, this one is similar can shed some light on your situation: [java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068423/java-net-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available-maximum-connections-reached)

There is also a write up about the same exception here:
http://dbaktiar-on-java.blogspot.com/2010/03/hudson-shows-buffer-space-available.html

Comment: we use websphere in Windows server more details in this pic : https://www9.0zz0.com/2022/01/04/08/694665433.png